# Keeping user on same page when he logs in

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I'am able to keep the user on the same page when he logs in on `Firefox` but on `IE` it loads the wamp folder directory. I presume this is a error and can it be fixed? To keep a user on the same page when he logs in is there a specific code to use?

The code I am using is a mix of PHP and ajax but the ajax is below;

```
function logMeIn(){
 var poststr="email="+$("#email").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val();
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../script/sendLogDetails.php",
  data: poststr,
  success: function(str){
   switch (str){
    case "1":
     alert("Can't connect to server - please retry later."); // Can't connect to server
     break;
    case "2":
     alert("Can't connect to database - please retry later."); // Can't connect to database
     break;
    case "3":
     alert("Account access problem - please retry later."); // Account access details
     break;
    case "4":
     alert("Invalid log in details - please retry."); // invalid login details
     break;
    default:
     window.location="";
     break;
    }
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you preventing the default form action?

Comment: what's the point of the `.location=""`?

Comment: Unrelated issue: You need to either URL-encode the values in `postr` or (my preference) make it an object instead of a string and let jQuery do the encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location="";` will redirect the user. Get rid of it.

Comment: that works but then there is no notification to say there is a log in. How would I add this ?